# Can't get value from object even if it's defined

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

I have some code in my page.

```
<td valign="top" class="contact-col3">
    <div>
        <p class="blueTxt">@(model.HasProperty("title3") ? model.GetProperty("title3").Value() : "")</p>
        @(model.HasProperty("abningstider") ? model.GetProperty("abningstider").Value() : "")
    </div>
</td>
```

When I run the code I get this error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

I've been running the debugger and this is what I see when I inspect the element just before the line runs.

[image]

The error appears at this line of code `@(model.HasProperty("abningstider") ? model.GetProperty("abningstider").Value() : "")`

Do anyone know a way to fix this or what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it could be this... It's

```
model.GetProperty("abningstider").Value
```

**not**

```
model.GetProperty("abningstider").Value()
```

(or, even better, it looks like you could do model.Abningstider as well?)

Comment: It can't be `("abningstider").Value` because `.Value` is a function so it needs `()`

Comment: Where do you see that? Did you try both my suggestions?

Comment: I ran it in the code, and VS tells you if it's a function or method or something else. Also `model.Abningstider` would and does not work, because Abningstider is not a declared property but a dynamically added property that umbraco loads.

Comment: I'd missed that you were on v8, sorry :-/

But model.Abningstider definitely should work - if you can see the property on your model while debugging I'd say it's available for you to use, no matter what VS says.

Answer (score 0):

You can use model.Abningstider if you are using ModelsBuilder and you are casting IPublishedContent to your typed model. If not, you should be using `model.Value("abningstider");`.

What you are doing in your code is accessing the property object instead, you don't need to do that. you are checking if the property exists in the doctype not if it has a value.

To check if the value exists use `HasValue()`:

```
@(model.HasValue("abningstider") ? model.Value("abningstider") : "")
```

If you are using ModelsBuilder you can use typed models but first you have to inherit your view from `UmbracoViewPage<>` and specify your model:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<YourModel>
```

Then you could use it like:

```
Model.Abningstider
```